# Importing data from Exchange/Outlook Journal

Tags: sql-server, outlook, exchange-server, journal

We have users that have custom forms that store data in their Outlook Journal. We need to get at that data to report on it and combine with other reports, but so far I haven't found many good solutions. Pushing the data out from Outlook on individual machines as say CSV and then importing to SQL Server is far from ideal. Better would be pulling from Exchange (not Outlook) and sending that to SQL Server on a schedule.

Anyone know of any methods, tools, APIs, anything to get at the Journal data in Exchange? Thanks!

Environment: 
Exchange 2010
Office/Outlook 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like [Exchange Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204119%28EXCHG.140%29.aspx) might be able to do what you are looking for.

You'll need to configure an account to have permissions to access the users' mailboxes, and you'll have to access them one at a time (or in parallel).  Other than that, you should be access the items in the user's Journal folder, read the items and process them as you need.

Comment: Thanks! I had actually forgotten all about that - I realized I had purchased the book *blushing* so that helped but it's old (2007) - finally stumbled across Exchange Web Services Managed API, which near as I can tell is very helpful. Read my own Journal (yay!). I agree as you say delegate permissions to mailboxes seem in order but other than that seem to have VS/LINQ/SQL (unfettered) access to that data, which I believe will be very helpful. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: also "Exchange Web Services Managed API" adds another layer of helpful and easy: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=c3342fb3-fbcc-4127-becf-872c746840e1